# Визуализация математических формул на C# (Windows-приложения)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, tex

Какую библиотеку посоветуете для визуализации TeX-формул на C#? В настоящее время использую библиотеку https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math, но в ней нет возможности подгружать модули (/usepackage) и многие полезные директивы не работают (/mathbb, /small, /big и др.)

Comment: https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath ?

Comment: @PakUula пробую разобраться, но не хотел бы уже во многом написанное приложение засорять ксамарином

Comment: А что делать? Вы хотите полноценный LaTeX, а не только математические формулы. Поэтому нужно тянуть большую хабазину. Нужно либо интегрировать реализацию LaTeX в ваше приложение, либо выносить его в отдельный серверный процесс и передавать в сервер задания для отрисовки.

Comment: @PakUula вообще мне сейчас нужны только математические формулы, но в них - символы, например \mathbb {R}, \mathbb {Z}, \varnothing, а также разные размеры скобок (чтобы лучше и не запутанно выглядела сложная формула), которые к сожалению не действуют в wpf-math

Comment: Похоже, никто, кроме CSharpMath, не поддерживает `amsfonts`. Видимо, другой альтернативы нет.